# Java Thread.suspend precise semantic

Tags: java, suspend, barrier

*This question is NOT about alternatives to Thread.suspend.
This is about the possibility to implement a bias lock with Thread.suspend, which (I believe) can't be implemented with Thread.interrupt or similar alternatives.*

I know Thread.suspend is deprecated.

But I want to know the precise semantics of Thread.suspend.

If I call thread1.suspend(), am I guaranteed to be blocked until thread1 is fully stopped? If I call thread1.resume(), can this call be visible to other threads out of order?

More over, if I successfully suspend a thread, will this thread be suspended at a somewhat safe point? Will I see its intermediate state (because Java forbids out of thin air value even in not properly synchronized program, I don't believe this is allowed) or see something out of order (if suspend is an asynchronous request, then sure I will see that kind of thing)?

I want to know these because I want to implement some toy asymmetric lock within Java (like BiasedLock in HotSpot). Using Thread.suspend you can implement a Dekker like lock without store load barrier (and shift the burden to the rare path). My experimentation shows it works, but since a Thread.sleep is enough to wait for a remote context switch, I am not sure this is guaranteed behavior.

By the way, are there any other way to force (or detect) remote barrier? For example, I search the web and find others use FlushProcessWriteBuffers or change affinity to bind a thread to each core. Can these tricks done within Java?

**EDIT**

I came up with an idea. Maybe I can use GC and finalizer to implement the biased lock, at least if only two threads are there. Unfortunately the slow path may require explicit gc() call, which isn't really practical.

If GC is not precise, I maybe end up with a deadlock. If the GC is too smart and collect my object before I nullify the reference (maybe the compiler is allowed to reuse stack variables, but is the compiler allowed to do these kind of things for heap variables, ignoring acquire fence and load fence? ), I end up with corrupted data.

**EDIT**

It seems a so called "reachability fence" is needed to prevent the optimizer moveing an object's last reference upward. Unfortunately it's no where.

Comment: I don't know about `Thread.suspend()` but since the debugger interface's suspend feature only stops at safe points, I would suspect the same here.

Comment: Yes, I know when a breakpoint is hit, the thread will be at a safe point. http://www.cliffc.org/blog/2015/02/22/how-does-java-both-optimize-hot-loops-and-allow-debugging/

Comment: But then is the suspend call synchronous?

Answer (score 0):

Its semantics consist entirely of what is specified in the Javadoc:

> Suspends this thread.
>   First, the checkAccess method of this thread is called with no arguments. This may result in throwing a SecurityException (in the current thread).
>
> If the thread is alive, it is suspended and makes no further progress unless and until it is resumed.

But as you're not going to use it, because it's deprecated, this is all irrelevant.

Comment: I know it's deprecated.

Comment: I know it's deprecated. I don't think its semantics consist entirely of what is specified in the Javadoc. Javadoc for this method is so incomplete (that is, what does it mean when it says "If the thread is alive, it is suspended"? Where are those "alive" and "suspended" defined? ). It's deprecated because it's easy to be used in a wrong way (that is, it is inherently deadlock-prone), but if you always resume very immediately after you suspend, why is it "inherently deadlock-prone"? Maybe it is reasonable to deprecate this method, but the doc is really really wrong.